Azure Pipelines, To run all my existing different pipelines after completion of one source pipeline
I have multiple microservices repos in azure. Each having its individual pipeline.
I want to trigger all microservices (child) pipelines after completion of one source pipeline A.
For this, I have added the "pipeline" resource in each microservice repo yaml file, which points to pipeline A using pipeline completion triggers taking ref. from doc.
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: A # Name of the pipeline resource.
    source: A # The name of the pipeline referenced by this pipeline resource.
    trigger: true # Run app-ci pipeline when any run of A completes

Now, above snippet is put in 'release/' branch of diff microservice. Note: Each microservice has its different branch used for pipeline.
But still child pipeline are not triggered after A. Reason being all child pipelines has 'main' as their default branch.
If I have to change that, I have manually go to 'each' pipeline UI trigger section and change 'Default branch for manual and scheduled builds' from main to respective release branch. And only then those will get triggered.
This process is very tedious as number of MicroServices(Child) pipelines are too many.
Can someone please guide through this? or if there is any other way than using 'pipeline resource'

Branch considerations does point to the downstream pipeline to be triggered.

If the two pipelines are in different repositories, the triggered pipeline version in the branch specified by Default branch for manual and scheduled builds is run.

It is easy to understand the design, since developers can have different versions of YAML pipeline definition files in different branches of one repo, and we don't want multiple versions of a single pipeline to be triggered to deploy different versions of code into probably the same service host environment. Therefore, the automated trigger behavior of a pipeline resource in this post is by-design and only the YAML pipeline definition in the Default branch for manual and scheduled builds receives the webhook of the the upstream pipeline resource completion.
With that being said, there are other ways to manually trigger downstream pipelines in parent pipeline A. Here is a sample you may consider, to InvokeRESTAPI to run pipeline in an agentless job and TriggerBuild via the marketplace extension task.
pipelineA.yml
trigger: none

variables:
  orgName: ${{split(variables['System.CollectionUri'], 'https://dev.azure.com/')[1] }}
  pipelineDefinitionIds: 10358,10359 # The definition ids of the downstream pipeline - Child1,Child2

jobs:
- job: UpstreamJob
  steps:
  - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
    artifact: drop

- ${{ each id in split(variables['pipelineDefinitionIds'], ',') }}:
  - job: TriggerDownstreamPipeline${{ id }}
    displayName: Call API to run pipeline with the definition id of ${{ id }}
    dependsOn: UpstreamJob
    pool: server
    steps:
    - task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
      inputs:
        connectionType: 'connectedServiceName'
        serviceConnection: 'AzureDevOpsServices' # https://dev.azure.com/
        method: 'POST'
        headers: |
          {
            "Content-Type":"application/json", 
            "Authorization": "Bearer $(system.AccessToken)"
          }
        body: |
          {
              "stagesToSkip": [],
              "resources": {
                  "repositories": {
                      "self": {
                          "refName": "refs/heads/release/deploy"
                      }
                  }
              },
              "variables": {}
          }
        urlSuffix: '$(orgName)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/pipelines/${{ id }}/runs?api-version=7.1-preview.1'
        waitForCompletion: 'false'

- job: TriggerDownstreamPipelinesWithExtension
  steps:
  - task: TriggerBuild@4
    inputs:
      definitionIsInCurrentTeamProject: true
      buildDefinition: '$(pipelineDefinitionIds)'
      queueBuildForUserThatTriggeredBuild: true
      ignoreSslCertificateErrors: false
      useSameSourceVersion: false
      useCustomSourceVersion: false
      useSameBranch: false
      branchToUse: 'release/deploy'
      waitForQueuedBuildsToFinish: false
      storeInEnvironmentVariable: false
      authenticationMethod: 'OAuth Token'
      enableBuildInQueueCondition: false
      dependentOnSuccessfulBuildCondition: false
      dependentOnFailedBuildCondition: false
      checkbuildsoncurrentbranch: false
      failTaskIfConditionsAreNotFulfilled: false



As per Branch filters, you can specify a list of branches to include or exclude in the trigger:
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: A
    source: A
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - main
        - releases/*
        exclude:
        - experimental/*

The good thing is that wildcards such as releases/* are allowed, so you don't have to change the trigger every time you create a new branch such as releases/1, releases/2 and so on.
But you do need to commit the pipeline file and related YAML templates in all the branches where the pipeline is supposed to run, including (but not limited to) the Default branch for manual and scheduled builds. Considering the example above, the pipeline file must exist in both the main and release/xxxx branches.
Please read carefully the Branch considerations.

The Branch considerations mentioned in Pipelines resource, point to the branches of pipeline A i.e. Parent Pipeline. Currently the snippet you provided will only work if I put it in main branch of every child pipeline, because 'Default branch for manual and scheduled builds' is main. If I change it in pipeline trigger UI to other branch only then it will run for other  branches. I want to be able to select target branch of child pipelines, and this not through UI but yaml.

Oh sorry I see what you're saying. I ran some tests using pipelines in the same repository, not pipelines in different repositories.

Anyway, you need to ensure that the microservices are always in a releasable state. When using trunk-based development deployments are done from the default branch (usually main or master), but if you don't want to do that maybe you can define a different branch such as releases/next, ready, etc and set that one as the default branch for manual and scheduled builds. Whenever the developers want to deploy a new version of a microservice they create or update this new branch. But honestly this is just a dirty workaround.

@cris7ronaldo are the microservices using the same branch name (e.g. /releases/sprint22) or does each team name it independently? How do you know which branch to use for each microservice?

Different developers handle different MS, so eg. 5 microservices will have different branchNames. I just want to automatically run all existing MS pipelines after completion of A. But since 'Default branch for manual and scheduled builds' of each MS pipeline is by default 'main', child pipeline not triggered. As a workaround, I have to manually go to each MS pipeline trigger setting in UI and change default branch to specific req. branch of each MS. But it very lengthy process. Need simpler solution.

Unless you reach some sort of agreement regarding the branch names or let the developers manage the Default branch for manual and scheduled builds you won't solve the problem.

Okay, If I manage to keep the branch names of all 5 Microservices as same eg. release/deploy, and put the pipeline resource snippet in each of these MS branches' yaml file, will child pipelines get triggered. I'm not sure as I have tried this once and it didnt trigger, after which I changed 'Default branch for manual and scheduled builds' of each pipeline to release/deploy, then it triggered correctly.

Yes you will still have to change the Default branch for manual and scheduled builds to eg. release/deploy. But you need to do this only once.
